# How do I remove multiple setIntervals from useEffect

Tags: reactjs, three.js, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm loading multiple animals into my ThreeJS project. All these animals have PositionalAudio with a setInterval function. I use them inside a useEffect function. On the callback I want to clear the interval, but it keeps calling the function.

This is the function where I set my setInterval:

```
const loadAudio = () => { 
  const animalSound = new THREE.PositionalAudio(listener);
  animalSound.setBuffer(animalBuffer);
  playSounds = setInterval(() => {
    animalSound.play();   
  } , 5000);
  audios.push(animalSound);
}
```

In the return function I try to clear the interval:

```
return () => {
  audios.forEach((audio) => {
    audio.stop();
    clearInterval(playSounds);
  });
};
```

Sadly the audio keeps playing every 5 seconds

Here is a code snippet

https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-tree-bb4ld?file=/src/App.js

Comment: could you please add your whole useEffect code snippet.

Comment: @AbuSufian I will, let me make a code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code snippet, say you have Button:

```
  <button
    onClick={buttonToggle}
    >
    {start ? 'start' : 'stop'}
  </button>
```

Initially we have some setup for useState and handle click function

```
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
  const [btnStart, setBtnStart] = useState(true);
  
  const buttonToggle = useCallback(
    () => setBtnStart(run => !run)
  , []);
```

In the useEffect you will do following changes

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(!btnStart) {
      // setSeconds(0); // if you want to reset it as well
      return;
    }
    
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds(seconds => seconds + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [btnStart]);
```